# THE CURSOR CURSOR NAME IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, db2, cobol

I created Dynamic Stored procedure for select. I'm going to use this generic query for execute multiple select statement, by passing the parameter.

```
DECLARE DESC_CSR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR V_SQL; 

SET V_SELECT =                               
'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||                
' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||                
' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||                
' WITH UR';                                  

PREPARE V_SQL FROM V_SELECT;  
OPEN DESC_CSR;
```

I will pass below values.

```
SELECT_FIELDS = B.COLUMN_A  INTO HOST_VAR_A
TABLE_NAME =  TABLE_A A   INNER JOIN TABLE_B B      
              ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
WHERE_CLAUSE = A.COLUMN_B = HOST_VAR_B
```

When I did this I got "THE CURSOR DESC_CSR IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE".

Could anyone please help me on how to PREPARE or correct me, if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You show only a part of your sproc, but not enough. Show your relevant exception handler. Show the __exact__ query before prepare.  Follow the documented instructions for SQL0514N in the Db2 Knowledge centre for your platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows).

Comment: @mao Thanks for the response. Below will be my query in PREPARE. Looks CURSOR didn't like, since i'm using INTO.

`SELECT B.COLUMN_A  INTO HOST_VAR_A
FROM TABLE_A A   INNER JOIN TABLE_B B      
              ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
WHERE = A.COLUMN_B = HOST_VAR_B`

Comment: You  have not provided the exception handler code  or Db2-server platform/version details. Do not use comments to add new facts (they get lost), instead __EDIT__ your question to add new facts. Your code example cannot produce that query unless the SELECT_FIELDS includes the `into` clause.

Comment: Separately, why have an INTO clause if you have a cursor ?   A singleton select does not need a cursor.

Comment: I tried SELECT without CURSOR like `SET V_SELECT =  'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS || ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||   ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE;  ||  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT; `  I got INTO CLAUSE IS NOT PERMITTED when passed SELECT_FIELDS as COLUMN_A INTO HOST_VAR_A.

Comment: Have you considered studying the sample programs in the Db2 Knowledge Centre to get basic comprehension about cursor usage? It can be more effective than asking duplicate questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: I think I found what is the issue. But have no idea how to handle it. Hope somebody can help.  I'm using  || WHERE_CLAUSE  || as parameter. after passing value it will look like ' WHERE  A.COLUMN_B = HOST_VAR_B'  My PREPARE fails with HOST_VAR_B is not acceptable in WHERE. If I pass where as 'WHERE  A.COLUMN_B = 101' with actual HOST_VAR_B. Its working fine. But I will not able to Hard code the HOST_VAR_B value since it will have to pass the HOST_VAR_B from program.

Comment: Study the docs and example code concerning parameter markers with dynamic-SQL and ensure you have some defence against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code and it working fine. I was able to run multiple select's using Dynamic.

```
DECLARE DESC_CSR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR V_SQL;  

  SET V_SELECT =                              
  'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||               
  ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||               
  ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||               
  ' WITH UR';                                 


  PREPARE V_SQL FROM V_SELECT;  

  OPEN DESC_CSR USING HOST_VAR_B;

  FETCH DESC_CSR INTO HOST_VAR_A;
```

I pass parm as below. using the where clause HOST_VAR_B as Parameter marker "?" and assigning the field at OPEN.

```
SELECT_FIELDS = B.COLUMN_A  INTO HOST_VAR_A
TABLE_NAME =  TABLE_A A   INNER JOIN TABLE_B B      
              ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
WHERE_CLAUSE = A.COLUMN_B = ?
```